# Cordova iOS audio and video tag's muted attribute not working?

Tags: javascript, cordova, audio, html5-video, html5-audio

We have a Cordova app that renders an HTML page that uses audio and video HTML tags for streaming audio and video.

Setting the muted attribute on these tags has no effect (always hear the sound) when rendering this page in Cordova.

If I render the same page in Safari (on the same iOS device) the muted attribute works as expected.

Anyone have any insight as to why muted doesn't work in Cordova?  Known issue?  Maybe a Webkit issue?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out iosrtc was "getting in way".   I ended up disabling the audio track instead of muting the html tag.

Answer (score 0):

The iosrtc plugin render the video as a "mock" html element. Not real html element. So every time changes made on that element, you need to refresh it natively using `cordova.plugins.iosrtc.refreshVideos()` function. This function will send command to native codes to refresh new attribute or changes on the `UIView` in native.

Here's some example I used before:

```
$(".muted-btn").on("click", function(){
   $("video").prop("muted", true);
   cordova.plugins.iosrtc.refreshVideos();
});
```

Even if you navigate to another page, the video element will stick to your view if you are not refreshing the `UIView` using the `refreshVideos()` function.